# Who wins arbitration between standard remote frame (11-bit identifier) and extended data frame(29-bit identifier)?

Tags: can-bus

So in case of a CAN bus having both CAN 2.0A and CAN 2.0B nodes, who wins arbitration when CAN 2.0A node tries to send remote frame (RTR bit = 1, IDE = 0) and CAN 2.0B tries to send data frame (SRR = 1 and IDE = 1). I have attached the image below for the reference.

[image: CAN Frames]

Will CAN 2.0A win the arbitration but how? IDE bit is dominant in case of CAN 2.0A but the CAN 2.0A controller does not include the IDE bit in arbitration as arbitration field is just 11-bit MSG ID and the RTR bit.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if 11 bit or 29 bit, everything between the start of frame bit and to the RTR bit is called "arbitration phase". Bus arbitration only happens during the transmission of these bits. Therefore a 29 bit frame with the same identifier as an 11 bit frame always loses arbitration. This is because of two reasons:

- The SRR (substitute remote request) bit of a 29 bit frame is always recessive (1).
- The IDE (identifier extension) bit of an 11 bit frame is always dominant (0). The meaning of this bit only exists in 11 bit frames - it is replaced with RTR in the 29 bit frame.

Answer (score 0):

Even though IDE bit isn't included in the arbitration of CAN 2.0**A** controllers, it's always 0 for them. During the transmission of IDE bit, CAN 2.0**B** controller detects that it has lost the arbitration, because it transmits 1 but reads 0 back. In this case, CAN 2.0**B** controller yields and arbitration is won by the CAN 2.0**A** controller.